# is there a better classification of a desirable algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, representation-theory

Consider a finite-dimensional, associative algebra presented as follows:
$$\mathcal{A} = e_1 \mathbb{R}\oplus e_2 \mathbb{R} \oplus \cdots \oplus e_n \mathbb{R} $$
with multiplication $*: \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ defined by linearly extending
$$  \color{red}{ e_i *e_j = C_{ij}^ke_k \qquad \text{no summation over $k$ intended}.} $$
For example, the direct product algebra $e_i*e_j = \delta_{ij}e_i$ fits this condition.

The clarity of the multiplication is partly from a good choice of notation. If I took a different basis then the multiplication could get muddled. For example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the commutative direct product algebra is described by $e_1 *e_1=e_1$ and $e_2*e_2=e_2$ and $e_1*e_2=0$. If I instead presented the multiplication by $f_1 = 2e_1+3e_2$ and $f_2=e_1+e_2$ then $f_1*f_1 = 5f_1-6f_2$.

Apparently I could be given an algebra where a proper change of notation would induce the $\color{red}{\text{desired property}}$. For the sake of this question, let us define $\mathcal{A}$ as **desirable** iff there exists some basis $\{f_1,\dots f_n \}$ for $\mathcal{A}$ such that $f_i *f_j = C_{ij}^kf_k$ where no summation is intended over $k$.

> **Question:** is there a more standard term for a desirable algebra?

Please point me towards a respected reference for your term if at all possible. Thanks is advance for your help!

Comment: To me this seems to be related to the terminology of having a multiplicative basis.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer that looks reasonable. However, I have yet to locate a good reference. A google search brought out many uses of the term... but, no origin. I have some reading to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A multiplicative basis of an algebra $A$ is a basis $B\subseteq A$ such that for all $b_1$, $b_2\in B$ we have either $b_1b_2\in B$ or $b_1b_2=0$ —sometimes, this is extended a bit by allowing in the first possibility that $b_1b_2$ be a scalar multiple of an element of $B$. In any case, this is more general than the semigroup algebras that Bill mentions, because I am allowing here the second option.

This is a pretty standard notion that comes up in the study of finite dimensional algebras. There are lots of algebras with multiplicative bases, the path algebra of a quiver being a basic example. Moreover, multiplicative bases show up in very important results.

One example: it is a theorem that finite dimensional algebras of finite representation type have multiplicative bases; this is a **very** difficult result due to R. Bautista, P. Gabriel, A. Roiter and L. Salmerón. The converse is not true, and there are group algebras, for example of infinite representation type.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to recall a text where this is stated?

Comment: The four authors have a paper with this result, but right now I can't give a precise reference because my connection to MathSciNet is not working. This result is probably discussed in the book by Gabriel and Roiter on the representation theory of algebras.

Answer (score 4):

If an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ (over $\mathbb{F}$) has a basis $\beta=\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$ such that for all $i,j$ we have $e_ie_j=e_k$ for some $k$, then $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{F}[\beta]$ is a **semigroup algebra**. If $\beta$ contains an identity (so it's a monoid), then $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{F}[\beta]$ is a **monoid algebra**. If $\beta$ also has inverses, then (of course) we have a good old **group algebra**.

As for the $\beta$ itself, like Julian, I would tend to call such a basis **multiplicative**. But I can't say that this is *standard* terminology. The term "multiplicative" is quite overused.